# <option Selected > is not working properly

Tags: lightning-web-components

Whenever I  load the page , the option is automatically selects the last
value of the picklist.  is not working.
how can I make the particular option value to Selected?
Please help me on this.

**HTML**

```html
<select size="1" name="Country Name" onchange={changeHandler}>
              <template for:each={CountryList} for:item="country">
   <option  selected={selectedCountry} key={country.key} value={country.Id}> 
      {country.Name}</option>
              </template>
  </select>
```

**js**

```js
 @track selectedCountry=false;
 @api countryId='';
 connectedCallback() {
 getCountry({
        recordId: this.countryId,
    })
.then(result => {
      this.CountryList= result;
      if(this.countryId){
        Object.entries(this.CountryList).forEach(
          ([key]) => {
            if(this.countryId === this.CountryList[key].Id){
              this.selectedCountry = true;
}
}
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are not using `lightning-combobox` here?

Comment: to avoid any lwc update in feature . @rahulgawale

Comment: Use this ready-made component from here `https://github.com/salesforce/base-components-recipes/tree/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/combobox` this is the source code of the same lwc base component.  You will need to use two component from this library combobox and baseCombobox

Answer (score 0):

If you just want last option to be selected you can do this

```
renderedCallback(){ var select=this.template.querySelector('select');
     
       if(select){
       select.selectedIndex = select.options.length-1;}

}
```

Comment: `i am getting the same issue from the below code
**js**
 @track selectedCountry;
 @api countryId='';
 connectedCallback() {
 getCountry({
        recordId: this.countryId,
    })
.then(result => {
      this.CountryList= result;
      if(this.countryId){
        Object.entries(this.CountryList).forEach(
          ([key]) => {
            if(this.countryId === this.CountryList[key].Id){
              this.selectedCountry = 'selected';
}
}`  @User6670

Comment: @sasha i have edited the answer